# EvtSubscribe and threading

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi

I am trying to write a log forwarded for Windows. The plan is simple - receive an event notification and then write it over a TCP socket. [This MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows that I should be using EvtSubscribe. However, I am confused as to how I should share the file descriptor for the open TCP socket. Will the EvtSubscribe callback block by default or will it thread or...?

Thank you in advance for any tips, picking up C++ on Windows after C on Linux has been a bit of a challenge for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs are quite sparse in details, but I reckon that it works as follows:

- If you use the subscription callback, then it will be called in a dedicated thread. So, if you delay in it, it will block further callbacks, but not other thread of the program
- If you use the SignalEvent, it will get signaled when the event arrives, and no threads are created automatically.

You can check that it is really another thread by calling GetCurrentThreadId() from the code that calls EvSubscribe() and from the callback, and compare the values.

My recommendation is to use the thread options, as the Event handlers in Windows are so difficult to be programmed correctly.

About sharing the TCP socket, you *can* share a socket between threads, but you should not write to it from more than one thread at a time. Nor read.

You can, however, read from one thread and write from another. Also, you can close the socket from one thread while other is in a blocking operation: it will get cancelled.

If you find this limiting, you should create a user thread and use it to send and/or receive data, while communicating with the other threads with queues, or similar.